# Get the Transformation-Matrix values in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, transformation-matrix

**Background** :

User click on **Mask** & upload their own image on the mask.

Once image uploaded, **Edit** Text is displaying on the image.

Once user click on **Edit** Text, we are displaying **pop up** box.

**Zoom** & **Rotate** buttons are displaying. Also user can **Drag** the uploaded image....

[image]

**Requirement** :

Once we Zoom, rotate or drag image,  I want to display the related **Transformation-Matrix** Values dynamically in console....

I am using these functions in Code snippet:

```
container.zoom 
container.rotate
container.onDragStart
container.onDragOver
```

**Code Snippet** :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 291,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 22,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                // Edit image

                if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
                    const span = $("<span class=\"pip pip" + newImageLoadedId + "\">" +
                        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark" + newImageLoadedId +
                        "\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit edit" +
                        newImageLoadedId + "\" >Edit </span></a>" +
                        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[
                            newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
                        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[
                            newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
                    });
                    span.attr('data-id', newImageLoadedId)
                    $("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" +
                            $('#demoTemplate').html() +
                            "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" +
                            newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>")
                        .appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                            "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
                            "top": "0px"
                        });
                }
                // end               
            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.zoom = function(delta) {
            settings.scale += delta;
            settings.scale = Math.max(0.5, Math.max(0, settings.scale));
            console.log('Zoom', settings.scale);     
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage();
        }

        container.rotate = function(rotation) {
            settings.rotate += rotation * Math.PI / 180;
             console.log('Rotation', settings.rotate);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage();
        }

        container.drawMask = function() {
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
          //context.setTransform('settings.x' , 0,0,'settings.y','context.translate','context.translate');
    //console.log('matrix', 'context.setTransform');
   context.restore();
            initImage = false;           
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("selected image, loading");
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

            //  remove button
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Draw started');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
          //  console.log('Drag over');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.drawMask();
                            container.drawImage();
                        }, 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

            // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
            // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
       
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

// Zoom

function zoom_in(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.zoom(0.1);
}

function zoom_out(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.zoom(-0.1);
}

// Rotate

function rotate_right(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.rotate(20);
}

function rotate_left(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.rotate(-20);
}
```

```css
.container {
        background: silver;
        position: relative;
    }

    .container img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .masked-img {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    .pip {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .edit {
        display: block;
        background: #444;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .edit:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }   

    .dark_content {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>

    <template id='demoTemplate'>
        <span>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="js-zoom-in" onclick="zoom_in(this)">Zoom In</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-zoom-out" onclick="zoom_out(this)">Zoom Out</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-rotate-right" onclick="rotate_right(this)">Rotate Right</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-rotate-left" onclick="rotate_left(this)">Rotate Left</button>
            </div>
            <img id="image" src="" style="display:none">
        </span>
    </template>
```

Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/4hmjc1gy/4/) & [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ardzqG) , [Full code in Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eR7RuNzW)

Comment: I tried to get values in this format : `matrix( scaleX(),skewY(), skewX(), scaleY(), translateX() , translateY())`

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get exactly what you're trying to achieve / problems you're facing (cuz, your code works fine for me). Can you please explain more?

Comment: @rv7 I tried this code : `context.setTransform('settings.x' , 0,0,'settings.y','context.translate','context.translate');` to get the transformation-matrix in console, but `transformation-matrix` is not displaying in console ....

Comment: @rv7   I want to get the `transformation-matrix of the image in console` as [here](https://imgur.com/kjOBY51) , similar to [website](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150)

Comment: Well, some properties in your format (like, skewX, skewY) are _never changed_ and also the scale is _common_ for X and Y. Isn't it? I think you meant the rotate instead of skew. One more thing, if I'd got you correctly, then I think that when the user zooms to **1.2** and rotates by **0.03**, then you expect the **log** as `matrix(1.2, 0.03, 0, 0)` (assuming there is no skew and the image was centered at origin) ?

Comment: @rv7 thanks you checked how zoom, rotate & drag works in the fiddle..... yes, you are right.... I did't used `skewX, skewY` , as now skew values are zero , can we keep those as (0,0) in transformation matrix ? as the standard `transformation matrix` have 6 values.... Please help me to display all 6 values in console...

Comment: in this [website](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150) also they did't used `skew`, but still they are displaying 6 values in transformation matrix....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `settings` object inside your `container.zoom` and `container.rotate` *event-handlers* is keeping track of the required values for the CSS `transform: matrix` value (except the *skew* property, which is neither required in present case).

The function:

```
function logTMatrix(obj) {
  console.log(`matrix( 
    scaleX(${ obj.scale.toFixed(2) }), 
    skewX(${ 0 }), 
    skewY(${ 0 }), 
    scaleY(${ obj.scale.toFixed(2) }), 
    translateX(${ obj.x }), 
    translateY(${ obj.y }) 
  )`);
};
```

will take the `settings` object as parameter and copy it to argument `obj` and will log the requirements!

```js
/*
 * Log_Transformation_Matrix function at line 182
 */
 
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 291,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 22,
            "name": "mask_2"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ]
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

                // Edit image

                if ($(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).length === 1) {
                    const span = $("<span class=\"pip pip" + newImageLoadedId + "\">" +
                        "<a onclick='document.getElementById(\"dark" + newImageLoadedId +
                        "\").style.display=\"block\";'><span class=\"edit edit" +
                        newImageLoadedId + "\" >Edit </span></a>" +
                        "</span>").insertAfter(".masked-img" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                        "left": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].x + (ImagePosition[
                            newImageLoadedId].width / 2) + "px",
                        "top": ImagePosition[newImageLoadedId].y + (ImagePosition[
                            newImageLoadedId].height / 2) + "px"
                    });
                    span.attr('data-id', newImageLoadedId)
                    $("<div id=\'dark" + newImageLoadedId + "\' class=\'dark_content\'>" +
                            $('#demoTemplate').html() +
                            "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"document.getElementById(\'dark" +
                            newImageLoadedId + "\').style.display=\'none\'\">Close</a>" + "</div>")
                        .appendTo(".pip" + newImageLoadedId).css({
                            "left": $('.edit' + newImageLoadedId).width() + 2 + "px",
                            "top": "0px"
                        });
                }
                // end               
            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// Image code

function logTMatrix(obj) {
  console.log(`matrix( 
    scaleX(${ obj.scale.toFixed(2) }), 
    skewX(${ 0 }), 
    skewY(${ 0 }), 
    scaleY(${ obj.scale.toFixed(2) }), 
    translateX(${ obj.x }), 
    translateY(${ obj.y }) 
  )`);
};

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
            rotate: 0,
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            scale = settings.scale,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.zoom = function(delta) {
            settings.scale += delta;
            settings.scale = Math.max(0.5, Math.max(0, settings.scale));
            //console.log('Zoom', settings.zoom);
            logTMatrix(settings);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage();
        }

        container.rotate = function(rotation) {
            settings.rotate += rotation * Math.PI / 180;
             //console.log('Rotation', settings.rotate);
            logTMatrix(settings);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            container.drawMask()
            container.drawImage();
        }

        container.drawMask = function() {
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling
            context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage
                .height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {
            const img = settings.image

            settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
            settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            context.save();
            context.translate(settings.x + img.width / 2, settings.y + img.height / 2);
            context.rotate(settings.rotate);
            context.scale(settings.scale, settings.scale);
            context.translate(-(settings.x + img.width / 2), -(settings.y + img.height / 2));
            let width = img.width,
                height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, width, height);
          //context.setTransform('settings.x' , 0,0,'settings.y','context.translate','context.translate');
    //console.log('matrix', 'context.setTransform');
   context.restore();
            initImage = false;           
        }

        // change the draggable image

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("selected image, loading");
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            initImage = true;
            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

            //  remove button
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
           // console.log('Draw started');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;

                $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
                container.selected(evt);
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                var img = new Image();
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
                evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');

            }
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
          //  console.log('Drag over');
            if (evt.target.getContext) {
                var pixel = evt.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                    if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                        var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                        var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                        if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                            return; // position has not changed
                        settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                        settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                        prevX = evt.clientX;
                        prevY = evt.clientY;
                        
                        // call logTMatrix here
                        logTMatrix(settings);
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            container.drawMask();
                            container.drawImage();
                        }, 10);
                    }
                } else {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            console.log('loading mask image from', imageUrl, from)
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

            // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
            // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        // Edit image
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
       
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));

// Zoom

function zoom_in(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.zoom(0.1);
}

function zoom_out(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.zoom(-0.1);
}

// Rotate

function rotate_right(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.rotate(20);
}

function rotate_left(button) {
    const id = $(button).parents('.pip').attr('data-id')
    JQmasks[id].item.rotate(-20);
}
```

```css
.container {
        background: silver;
        position: relative;
    }

    .container img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .masked-img {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    .pip {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .edit {
        display: block;
        background: #444;
        border: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }

    .edit:hover {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
    }   

    .dark_content {
        display: none;
        position: relative;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        padding: 16px;
        border: 16px solid orange;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1002;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>

    <template id='demoTemplate'>
        <span>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="js-zoom-in" onclick="zoom_in(this)">Zoom In</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-zoom-out" onclick="zoom_out(this)">Zoom Out</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-rotate-right" onclick="rotate_right(this)">Rotate Right</button>
                <button type="button" class="js-rotate-left" onclick="rotate_left(this)">Rotate Left</button>
            </div>
            <img id="image" src="" style="display:none">
        </span>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it working fine.... when i checked [link](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/) , they are displaying [this image](https://i.imgur.com/W5p13KB.png) , so on 4th position , they have `Scale(y)` , is that correct ? because in 4th position we are dispaying `rotation`..... in our case, only scale(x) is present.....